# Is there a comprehensive database of African elections that includes the number of electoral constituencies?

Tags: africa, elections, district

Datasets like QOG and VDEM include statistics like district magnitude, but without the actual number of electoral districts, one cannot calculate district magnitude from scratch. I have also consluted the IPU database which contains scattered information, but does not cover all African elections.